# pyinstaller + eel . Не запускается файл

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

Написал код на питоне с использованием eel. Скомпилировал через pyinstaller. Не запустился. Указал --debug all. Всё шло, но возникла ошибка, что нет какого-то файла '-'. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте вместо флага `--debug all` поставить `--debug imports --debug bootloader`